# Перестали работать логин и регистрация Laravel

Tags: laravel, auth

Только только создал Laravel проект. Реализовал Регистрацию через make:auth. Таблицы в БД появились, на топ панели вкладки регистрация и авторизация тоже. На страницы можно зайти, ввести данные в поля,
([Регистрация](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4XW3.jpg))
 но при нажатии на Register или Login сразу загружается страница "419 | Page Expired " и вообще ничего. 
Создал новый проект - все стало отлично. Смог зарегистрироваться и залогиниться. Больше ничего не менял, сегодня захожу - опять всё Expired([Expired Ошибка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7t79.jpg))

UPD. Обнаружил что куки lavarel_session при создании expire at "мое время -(минус) 1 час". Именно из за этого такая ошибка. Стандартное время жизни 2 часа. А так как у меня +3 часа( московское время) он у меня expire at на час раньше. Я понял что ошибка здесь кроется. Но как это исправить ?

UPD2. Изменил длительность жизни куки на 4 часа вместо 2х. Теперь Expire at показывает на час вперед. Но все равно при логине и регистрации пишет Page expired

Comment: Попробуй почистить кэш браузера

Comment: пробовал чистить.

Comment: Проверьте в настройках `config/app.php` какая таймзона указана.